# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl

Tags: java, maven, jboss, cxf, jax-ws

)

I've got a small problem today! I'm trying to deploy an application on a Jboss server (AS 7.0)...

When I'm working on my own computer (localhost), no problem, everything is fine. But after deploying my war on the server when I realize one action I've got an horrible error :

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider: Provider com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl could not be instantiated: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl
java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:207)
java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:164)
java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:353)
java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:421)
javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.getProviderUsingServiceLoader(Provider.java:146)
javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.provider(Provider.java:106)
javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:57)

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl
java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:345)
java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:421)
javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.getProviderUsingServiceLoader(Provider.java:146)
javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.provider(Provider.java:106)
javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:57)
```

I'm using Apache CXF and all my jars are maven dependencies in my build path (jaxws-rt 2.2.8, jaxws-api...)

Do you think it may be a problem on the Jboss ? When I deploy this war on a Tomcat I don't have this problem :(

Thanks to all

Comment: What are the `<scope>`s of the dependencies in your `pom.xml`?

Comment: Yes. It could be Jboss. These application servers comes bundled with tons of jars and causes the classloader to load the their version of jar. Try to test with jboss on your local instead of using tomcat.